# How can I make a float throw an exception, when entered?

Tags: try-catch

I have a GUI that I use as a calculator. When I enter in anything other than numbers, it throws a NumberFormatException, as intended. But when I enter in a number such as "23423f" the program seems to think I'm entering a float and doesn't throw an exception, because of the f at the end, even though all other letters throw an exception.

Currently, all I'm doing is putting the input section into a try catch block, where I parse it into a double, and having it catch a NumberFormatException if there is one (because only numbers can be parsed into doubles), and another catch block to throw an IllegalArgumentException from an if statement for any input less than 0.

That's just a guess, but I don't know why else only f at the end wouldn't throw an exception.

```
        try
        {
        // get the total sales. the input is a string
           stringInput = salesInputField.getText();
                double validAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringInput);
                if (validAmount < 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        // calculate the sales and county tax
           stateTaxes = validAmount * STATE_TAX;
           countyTaxes = validAmount * COUNTY_TAX;

        // display a message dialog showing the miles
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "State Sales Tax: " + percent.format(stateTaxes) + "\n" +
                                                "County Sales Tax: " + percent.format(countyTaxes) + "\n",
                                                "Taxes Owed",
                                                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
           catch (NumberFormatException error)
           {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException error)
           {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           }
```

Comment: Not all other letters, 'd' for double will also be accepted, as well as 'e' for the exponent as in '1.2e+3'

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your theory is probably correct since the input you described is a valid float/double number, so you would expect to be able to parse it.

Obvious solution is to check that the string only contains what you consider valid chars (presumably something like dddd.dd).

A general comment: store money values as integers otherwise you can end up with horrible rounding stuff going on. Don't take my word for it, just google it.

Comment: +1 for 'don't use floating points for money'. Use BigDecimal.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. "Obvious solution is to check that the string only contains what you consider valid chars (presumably something like dddd.dd)." Is there a method that can be used to do that?

Comment: Have a look at the NumberFormat class. Basically create a NumberFormat with what you conside valid and use it to parse your string. If the parser fails the string is invalid.